# Laravel pluralization in validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm developing a multilanguage API and I need to return the translated Bag using pluralization.

Examples:

`'item' => 'required|min:1'` should return

> item must have at least 1 **character**

`'item' => 'required|min:2'` should return

> item must have at least 2 **characters**

Any idea of how to translate the bag other than iterate the array?

I tried in the lang file:

> :attribute must have at least :min character|:attribute must have at least :min characters

and

> {1} :attribute must have at least :min character|[2,*] :attribute must have at least :min characters.

Comment: make folder for other language like en folder in lang directory and create validation.php file in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laravel **trans_choice** you can do that:

In your code

```
    $rules = [
        'item' => 'required|min:1'
    ];

    $attributeNames = array(
        'item' => 'Item'
    );       

    // Pass your length here
    $msg = [
        'min' => trans_choice('validation.min', 1)
    ];

    $this->validate($request,$rules,$msg,$attributeNames);
```

In lang/en/validation.php

```
'min' => ':attribute must have at least :min character|:attribute must have at least :min characters'
```

Refere this URL [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#pluralization)